# How to use DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler to handle database corruption in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Some of the live users of my app are experiencing **SQLite database corruption**. When we have collected log from users we found below details:

```
E/SQLiteLog(14085): (11) database corruption at line 57189 of [b3bb660af9]
E/SQLiteLog(14085): (11) Invalid page count: nPage: 52, nPageFile: 50
E/SQLiteLog(14085): (11) lockBtree() error, rc: 11, printing out first page (size: 32768) of  DB /data/data/com.app.testpackagename/files//db/statictext_v3.0_DE.db
E/SQLiteLog(14085): (11) Page (1) has been corrupted

E/SQLiteLog(13318): (11) database disk image is malformed
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(13318): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/com.app.testpackagename/files//db/statictext_v3.0_DE.db
E/SQLiteLog(13318): (11) database corruption at line 57189 of [b3bb660af9]
E/SQLiteLog(13318): (11) Invalid page count: nPage: 52, nPageFile: 50
E/SQLiteLog(13318): (11) lockBtree() error, rc: 11, printing out first page (size: 32768) of  DB /data/data/com.app.testpackagename/files//db/statictext_v3.0_DE.db
E/SQLiteLog(13318): (11) Page (1) has been corrupted
```

The corrupt database is the **Static database** (it has preloaded records and we are not doing any **Insert**, **Update**, **Alter**, **Delete** except **Select** data from it.

This database is in assets of my app and I'm mounting it to device and obtaining its object with

```
this.staticDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(AppDelegate.getFileDirectory() + "/" + SDCARD_FOLDER_NAME +DB_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + Dbpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

I want to handle this exception with [DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.html)  by using `onCorruption` method of this class but not getting any proper documentation for implementation. Can I use this class in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getFileDirectory() + "/" + "sd_card_name" + "db_folder_name" + "/" + "dbPath",
                null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY,
                new DatabaseErrorHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase dbObj) {
                        //do whatever you want to do
                    }
                });
```

Comment: it works for me but requires 'SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE' instead of 'SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY'

Comment: Depends on what kind of connection you want to establish with the database

Answer (score 0):

The [database implementation](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java) just tries to open the database again after the handler was called:

```
private void open() {
    ...
        try {
            openInner();
        } catch (SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException ex) {
            onCorruption();
            openInner();
        }
    ...
```

So what you have to do is to replace the database file with a working copy.

The `DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler` is not useful for you; you have to implement your own [`DatabaseErrorHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseErrorHandler.html) and give it to `openDatabase()`.

Comment: can i override onCorruption() callback in my class

Comment: Yup, you can. I added an answer

Comment: @CL. I think the `openInner` call second time is to give a retry. If that fails too, the exception is caught and database connection closed. It makes sense